# I generated classes from an XML schema using xsd. How do I write them back to XML?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xsd

The XML schema specifies an index of files. Below is an example of how the XML file should look like.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fIndex xsi:schemaLocation="http:address fIndex.xsd" xmlns="address" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <f>
    <foN>SomeDir</foN>
    <fiN>file1.txt</fiN>
  </f>
  <f>
    <foN>SomeDir</foN>
    <fiN>file2.txt</fiN>
  </f>
</fIndex>
```

I used xsd to create the classes needed for the XML. Then filled in some sample code to match the example above.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            fileIndexType table = new fileIndexType();

            fileIndexTypeF element1 = new fileIndexTypeF();
            fileIndexTypeF element2 = new fileIndexTypeF();

            element1.fiN = @"C:\SomeDir";
            element1.foN = @"file1.txt";
            element2.fiN = @"C:\SomeDir";
            element2.foN = @"file2.txt";

            fileIndexTypeF[] files = new fileIndexTypeF[2] { element1, element2 };
            table.f = files;
        }
    }
```

How do I create the above XML file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to [*serialize*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) the objects.

The [`XmlSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) class can be used for this:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(fileIndexType));
using(Stream writer = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create))
{
  serializer.Serialize(writer, table );
  writer.Close();
}
```

Comment: @Kasper Hansen - the reverse process (hydrating an object graph from a file such as an XML file) is called deserialization.

Comment: Yes. Thank you. I was a bit lost. Now I know what to read up on.

Comment: @Kasper Hansen - Glad I could help. You may want to look at the [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) as well.

Comment: @John Saunders - fair point... I never remember to do so in my own code... (hangs head in shame)